# I have a curiosity about notation of scheme

Tags: scheme

*I want to make one function which for the below language defined using the BNF notation.*

*expr := '[' op  expr  expr ']' |  number*

*op   :=  '+'  |  '-'  |  '*'  |  '/'*

*For example, suppose function name is funct, then*

```
(funct '(+ 1 3)) => 4
(funct '(+ (- 3 1) 4) => 6
```

*Please give me a hint or example code*

Comment: What is the relevance of your code example?

Comment: You have changed the question to something completely different. For the future If you find your old question not useful for other users delete and make new questions. If your old question was useful for others accept the best answer and move on. If everyone edited just one question this site would have been short of many good answers to many good questions.

Comment: @Sylwester I suspect the OP had a case of the XY problem. It happens frustratingly often.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Sadly the original question was interesting, specially since R7RS retracted the use of square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you thinking of something like this?

```
(define (ev exp)
  (cond
    ((number? exp)       exp)
    ((not (list? exp))   (error "not a list"))
    ((< (length exp) 2)  (error "list too short"))
    (else 
     (apply (case (car exp)
              ((+) +)
              ((-) -)
              ((*) *)
              ((/) /))
            (map ev (cdr exp))))))
```

then

```
> (ev '(+ 1 3))
4
> (ev '(+ (- 3 1) 4))
6
```

Comment: P.S. All of those operators work with one argument too, and `+` and `*` also work with zero arguments. So the length check you have in your code may be overly restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

In Racket this works straight out of the box:

```
[+ 2 3]
=> 5
```

Check with your interpreter, it's possible that you won't have to do anything for this to work.

Comment: I want to write any function in Scheme for the following language defined using the BNF notation [+ 2 3].It can't use in DrRacket. So I want to make function [+ 2 3], not (+ 2 3).